# How can I disable zoom and zoom out for safari ios 13 ? (in my webpage)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, google-chrome

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

this code does not work, idk what to do i find out some other codes but they aren't working..Thank You
(Also I don't know if it works at android , because im using ios i can check it only in ios for now)

Comment: plz try this code..  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

Comment: This meta tag code for avoiding zoom effect for input box.. Do u have input box pbm?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0"> this code works now thank you so much